# raphael js and real-time graph

Tags: graph, real-time, raphael

i have used http://cristian.nexcess.net/ajax/svg_chart/ demo to create real-time graphs, but want to know if i can use raphael js to create similar line charts ?

has anyone tried real-time graphs with raphael js?

Thanks

Comment: +1 : Did you find a solution ? I'm also interested

Comment: http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket Might be an interesting start point

Answer (score 2):

I've made real-time graph using Raphael JS library - here is how http://nme.pl/en/2011/01/real-time-graph-using-javascript - it should work in any browser.

You might be interested in more lightweight solution, which is based on html5 canvas (see the link above).